Gigya Timeout Android
I developed a flutter app, I have the Google cloud services side configured correctly (package name and SHA1) in debug mode, it works fine and I can log in using Google accounts. But when I compile the android app in release mode and pressed the Google button, it stays waiting until it generates Timeout, specifically the exception is:
GigyaTimeout(ErrorCode: 504002, Message:The request timed out., status code:500)
It looks rare to me that everything works well in debug mode and not in release, am I missing some configuration on the Google cloud console or SAP side?
The library I am using is:
https://pub.dev/packages/gigya_flutter_plugin
PD1. Also for the release version I have registered the package name and the SHA1 in release mode.
PD2. Using the gigya_flutter example app I get the same result.
I changed the configuration, also I used the same compilation config for debug mode, but the result is the same.
